# Preventing the voltage between two isolated grounds from exceeding max rating

Tags: grounding, isolation, floating

Consider the low-side current sensing application shown in Figure 1. Grounds 1 and 2 are galvanically isolated. Assume, for example, ground 1 is the NEUTRAL line on mains power (\$V_g\$), and ground 2 comes from an isolated DC power supply whose power +/- terminals are both floating relative to local EARTH ground.

The current sensor IC's data sheet gives an absolute maximum rating for the working voltage \$V_{WORKING}\$ between the IP+/- pins and "all other pins" on the IC. *(n.b. To keep things simple, the IC's power ground pin (connected to ground 2) is the only "other pin" that's shown.)*

I'm wondering what techniques I could/should use, if anything, to ensure the working voltage between ground 1 and floating ground 2 (\$|V_{12}|\$) never exceeds \$V_{WORKING}\$? *(And note that in other applications, grounds 1 and 2 might **both** be floating relative to local EARTH ground.)*

[image]
Figure 1.

Comment: You could put a TVS diode between the two grounds, perhaps. Or anything else with the proper nonlinear I-V characteristic.

Comment: connect 2 to 1 and isolate the output.

Comment: Regarding "connect 2 to 1 and isolate the output", that solution merely "kicks the can down the road". I now need to deal with the potential difference (voltage) between the combined 1|2 ground and galvanically isolated ground #3 on the other side of the isolation barrier.